# Underline in timeline

Tags: bug, design, timeline

If question title is long enough, underline in the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/288480/timeline) appears only under first line of text:

> [image: long title]

Comment: Classic text overflow, better hide such overflow IMO