# Title on privilege pages look duplicated on small screen

Tags: feature-request, bug, design, privileges-page

When the device screen width is small enough on some privilege pages, e.g. [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) the page title looks duplicated:

> [image: narrow]

After increasing the width all falls into place:

> [image: wide]

I suggest to remove the secondary text and the final `>` symbol from the page title to eliminate visual duplication.

Comment: What’s also weird is that the privilege name is put below the divider line instead of above it.

Comment: @Laurel such behavior is possibly related to [another bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289100/339911).

Answer (score 3):

I think this happens because the top of the page shows the path through the help center to get to the page, and below that is the title of the page:

[image]

When the screen is too small, the end of the path gets pushed down to the next line:

[image]

I think the title should be removed and the path should be kept so this doesn't happen on small screens and so the name isn't unnecessarily repeated.