# Flag summary page title may overflow into description block for non-English UI sites

Tags: bug, design, localization, flag-history, responsive-design

In case of localized sited (in particular for Stack Overflow in Russian) and for a small screen there is a design issue with the head block of the flag summary page. For instance title of the current filter name may overwrap into the description block:

> [image: user name]

There is also an issue with long titles, but as I noticed recently this already posted by Monica Cellio: [Flag-summary page is *mostly* responsive, but post titles overflow into the stats box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319779/339911)

Another related issue is a generation of filter title string for localized sites: [Impossible to localize flag summary page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911)

BTW, text overflow for a long title, but for timeline page is already reported by me more than 2 years ago: [Underline in timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289100/339911)

Comment: Also related: [The fixed size of the div containing deleted flagged posts causes display issues on small screens](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379814/1364007)