# Long question titles 'underflow' in timeline

Tags: bug, timeline, responsive-design

When viewing the [timeline of a question with a long title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/343055/timeline) on a narrow screen, the title divides itself both over and under the header line:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate from [Jan 1 '17](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289100/underline-in-timeline), 32 months earlier.